# How to use jquery to decode the return json object?

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-plugins

I trid to use an upload plugin for jQuery.
http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

When I set the returning respond type to json, firefox will popup a dialog asking how I like to handle the returning json object.

People have asked the same question at the upload script's author's page but no answer so far. Hopefully javascript guys here can figure out how we can handle this.

Thanks.

```
<script type= "text/javascript">
      /*<![CDATA[*/
        $(document).ready(function(){

            /* example 1 */
            var button = $('#button1'), interval;
            new AjaxUpload(button, {
                //action: 'upload-test.php', // I disabled uploads in this example for security reasons
                action: '/posts/upload_images/', 
                name: 'myfile',
                responseType: 'json',
                onSubmit : function(file, ext){
                    // change button text, when user selects file           
                    button.text('Uploading');

                    // If you want to allow uploading only 1 file at time,
                    // you can disable upload button
                    this.disable();

                    // Uploding -> Uploading. -> Uploading...
                    interval = window.setInterval(function(){
                        var text = button.text();
                        if (text.length < 13){
                            button.text(text + '.');                    
                        } else {
                            button.text('Uploading');               
                        }
                    }, 200);
                },
                onComplete: function(file, response){
                    var json = response;
                    alert(json);
                    button.text('Upload');

                    window.clearInterval(interval);

                    // enable upload button
                    this.enable();

                    // add file to the list
//                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#example1 .files').text(json.response_text);                     
                    $('<li></li>').appendTo('#example1 .files').text(file);                     
                }
            });
        });
    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for a solution for the same script and stumbled upon this page. I didn't found a solution online so here's how I fixed it:

@ `upload-file.php`:
replace

```
echo "success".$cc;
```

with

```
echo json_encode(array(
status' => 'success',
'id' => $picid,
'image' => $imgurl
));
```

@ `front end`:
replace

```
var bb=response.substr(0,7)
var idd=response.replace('success',' ');
var idb =idd.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g,'');
if(bb==="success")
{
    $('<span></span>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="images/'+file+'" alt="" width="120" height="120" style="margin:5px;" />').addClass('success');
}
else
{
    $('<span></span>').appendTo('#files').text(file).addClass('error');
}
```

with

```
var what = jQuery.parseJSON(response);
if(what.status == 'success')
{
    $('<span id='+what.id+'></span>').appendTo('#files').html('<img src="'+what.image+'" alt="" width="120" height="120" style="margin:5px;" /><br><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="deleteFile('+what.id+');">Delete</a>').addClass('success');
}
else 
{
    $('<span></span>').appendTo('#files').text(response).addClass('error');
}
```

And to actually answer this question.

`jQuery.parseJSON(response);`

does..

Answer (score 2):

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert( obj.name === "John" );
```

Answer (score 1):

This jQuery plugin makes it simple to convert to and from JSON: http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/

Also, you might be interested in [this comment](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/#comment-769) on the blog post you referenced:

> Sorry to spam your blog post (which is great), but I thought I’d mention that I found the problem:
>
> For whatever reason, the response always has `<pre>` tags around the entire response when the response is of type `plain/text`. That was causing the `eval()` call to fail. My current solution was just to strip those tags off before the `eval()` call and now everything works. Not a great solution but at least I can keep working for now.

Comment: I can't speak from experience, but hopefully the plugin he is using doesn't require yet another plugin for decoding JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This may be it, I don't know because I know nothing about that plugin, but you may need to take a look at the response type you are setting on the server-side of things; you should set the HTTP response to have a content/MIME type of something like "text/plain", "text/javascript" or "application/javascript" - see if that fixes your problem.

Comment: My response type is "application/json". And I had another ajax testing app which send a text from a form and the backend responses back using json, which the front end then prompts up properly. So I dont think i have problem in my backend which handling data and send back json. That test app use jquery's jquery.post only.

Comment: Gotcha - well, good luck. If I had the time, I would probably look at this more closely. But it's Saturday and I have other things to do. :) Hope you find a solution soon!

Comment: I am now thinking there might be something wrong with my backend. I am using django and will try to read and download some demo to see how other people handle the json. Will post again later. Thanks guys.